# DVD won't play in Ubuntu Jaunty after codes and css support has been added

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, media-player, ubuntu-9.04, totem

Using Totem Video Player v2.26.1 on Ubuntu Jaunty 9.04, dvd's won't play after I've installed *libdvdread4*, added the *Medibuntu* packages, and run

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

If I click on the dvd I get an error *"Could not read from resource".  If I navigate to one of the videos directly and run it, the movie will play, but with obvious degradation or encryption (like cable tv you aren't paying for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkAround: Switch to [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: technically that's a "workaround" ... VLC does its own decss, so if that's why Totem isn't working, no other program that relies on the system decss will work either.

Comment: Good point.  I'd still like to get another answer (that's why I haven't accepted it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.   I run Ubuntu 9.10 but I doubt this issue has much to do with the version of ubuntu.  If you have all the dvdcss stuff installed AND VLC doesnt work (has css built into it) then it is not likely css.

I looked into the /var/log/syslog file and found an error about the region not matching.

So I ran regionset  (see this link for more information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) and set the region from FF to FE.   FF *i think* is "not set" and FE is region 1.

sudo apt-get install regionset
sudo regionset
regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
Current Region Code settings:
RPC Phase: II
type: NONE
vendor resets available: 4
user controlled changes resets available: 5
drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF

Would you like to change the region setting of your drive? [y/n]:y
Enter the new region number for your drive [1..8]:1
New mask: 0xFFFFFFFE, correct? [y/n]:y
Region code set successfully!

Then dvd playback worked perfectly.